# How to create a random video from a random picture annd random audio file

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, mp4

I am working on a batch conversion process where I need to add a random picture (a `.jpg`) on a random `.mp3` and make an `.mp4`.

This is the code I am using in terminal *Mac OS* X putting all the `.mp3` and the `.jpg` in the same folder:

```
for f in *.mp3; do /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1_1/bin/ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i abc5.jpg  -i "$f" -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -vf scale=1280:720 -shortest "${f%mp3}mp4"; done
```

It works great, but I don't know how to add another random feature for the `.jpg` files, so every time I have to put a different `.jpg` and change the name (usually in the file not in the script). I also know this must be something with for ((..., but I don't know how to add it properly.

```
for f in *.mp3; do /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1_1/bin/ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i abc5.jpg  -i "$f" -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -vf scale=1280:720 -shortest "${f%mp3}mp4"; done
```

Comment: I am confused by the wording. What do you mean by "add another random feature for the `.jpg` files"? Also, how does the first block of code differ from the second block?

Comment: hi sorry bad english.in few words... in the same folder i have different .mp3 and different .jpg and i want to make the videos using any of the .jpg to be applied on any of the .mp3. for now i have used the above code...(which i have copied twice that's and error of mine they not differ at all)...it runs on a folder where i have many .mp3 but i have to specifiy each time the name of the .jpg...i am trying to use the command FOR incapsulated but it seems to not work...